# Successful deployment from Visual Studio, but Sharepoint site shows old content

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

My company are working at Sharepoint site that we are developing using Visual Studio. The actual installation at the customer is performed by scripts deploying the produced wsp-files. During normal development I mostly use deployment from directly from inside Visual Studio. Unfortunately I often run into problems when trying to deploy my solutions. We are using a server-farm set up, but each developer has their own virtual server, datebase instance and so on.

We have one project file that the define the basic content-type used for different department. This content-type typically define stuff like what period that the list item cover. Each department have their own project that uses the content type combined with department specific fields to form the final list.

One of my current problems is that when I make edits to the content type and deploy it the changes does not seem to propagate. Even though I rebuild the solution and deploy both the base project and the department project with success I still see the old version of the content fields when I create a new department list. Sometimes it helps to retract the projects, but often I literally have to restart everything before it works.

My question is if this problem is caused by Visual Studio not really deploying my new defintions or if there is some architectual aspect of Sharepoint 2010 that might prevent the change to propagate. What steps can I take to lessen the likelihood of the problem occuring?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the content type with Central Administration before doing a new deployment? I've found out that Sharepoint don't update/create content types when it finds other one with the same name.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have since I posted the question tried to use Central Adminstration to clear the content type, but even though it gave some relief it didn't solve all problems. 

It seems the problem might be connected to Sharepoint behaving differently if it believes the content type is still in use or if it is free to delete. For instance if there are lists left with content that refer to content type it Sharepoint seems to leave the content type. When you try to update the type Sharepoint recyle the old type and you wish you never started the refactoring.